# Determining which vlan a machine is on

Tags: networking, vlan

On a linux machine, is there a way using `ip` (or `ifconfig`) to determine which vlan is being used by an instance?

Comment: if you have physical server in cisco network you can try to capture the cdp package

Comment: This is not usual to find the VLAN in Linux machine. Easy to find it in Router/ Switch Layer 3. But, I thought this can be found by using wireshark to discover the way of package on going. Maybe you will see the VLAN ID. Basically, all of package follows the routing table to find out the way, and VLAN is the way need to pass. Please update to me if I have any incorrect. Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree with @TienPhan about using wireshark or similar. Tagged packets contain an additional header, (See: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-and-how-are-ethernet-vlans-tagged).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If youre using cisco network equipment, the VLAN will be visible in the cdp info packet. To get the cdp packet using tcpdump you can do the following. Obviously the network team will have to enable cdp, which they often turn off to protect this info. The vlan will be visible.

```
tcpdump -nn -v -i eth0 -s 1500 -c 1 'ether[20:2] == 0x2000'
```

I'll add that you can see if an interface had been configured to use a vlan from ifconfig. Youll see something like `eth0.22` when `eth0` has had a vlan 22 tag added. This does not mean that the tag has been added to this server though. This will only be seen on the switch. If the switch has also been configured to send cdpinfo packets, you can query this to tell for sure from the server... otherwise not.

Comment: + 1 for tcpdump example, but what about non-cisco, i.e., regular linux?

Comment: I was hoping for something other than tshark or wireshark, but at least tcpdump explicitly states the VLAN ID on the cli. Thanks!

Comment: @LucasRamage - yes, you can tell which interfaces have been configured to use a vlan, ill add it to answer, but this doesnt tell you if the server is actually on that vlan, this can only be seen on the switch.